# Using TextWriter with StreamWriter and Reading/Writing Simultaneously

Tags: c#, stream, streamwriter, filesystemwatcher

As the title suggests, I'm attempting to read and write to a file at the same time. I have researched this topic but the answers I have found don't seem to work for me because of the circumstances in my program. I am using multiple FileSystemWatchers to track a large amount of files that are constantly passing through a flow in my network. As the files pass through each part of my flow, a text file is updated(one text file per spot in the flow) that marks the name of the file and the time it was created within the folder. It is unpredictable when files might be passing through, and when they might be writing to the tracker text files. My goal is to be able to read and write to the file simultaneously, in case a user attempts to read to from a text file that is being written to at the exact same time. How would I accomplish this?

```
//Write to File
    private void WriteToFile(string info,string path,string tr)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(path+@"\"+@tr))
        {
            var myFile =
            File.Create(path + @"\" + @tr);
            myFile.Close();
            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path + @"\" + @tr, true);
            tw.WriteLine(info,true);
            tw.Close();
        }
        else if (File.Exists(path + @"\" + @tr))
        {
            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path + @"\" + @tr, true);
            tw.WriteLine(info);
            tw.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add the code which is responsible for reading the file, to your question? Thanks!

Comment: if you use FileStream, you can lock part of the file  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.lock or use the FileShare.None option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *circumstances* you are alluding to seem to say that while multiple attempts can be made to read/write the file at a given time, you still want to ensure that the operations are performed one after another in the correct order that the read or writes got called.

One simple method of ensuring that the *read* and *write* operations are synchronized would be to just put a `lock` or `Monitor` around the methods. Try the following code for your *write* method:

```
private readonly object _locker = new object();

// write the file
private void WriteToFile(string info, string path, string tr)
{
    Monitor.Enter(this._locker);

    try
    {
        if (!File.Exists(path + @"\" + @tr))
        {
            var myFile =
            File.Create(path + @"\" + @tr);
            myFile.Close();
            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path + @"\" + @tr, true);
            tw.WriteLine(info, true);
            tw.Close();
        }
        else if (File.Exists(path + @"\" + @tr))
        {
            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path + @"\" + @tr, true);
            tw.WriteLine(info);
            tw.Close();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Monitor.Exit(this._locker);
    }
}
```

Then, I would use a very similar construct for *reading* the file.

```
// read the file
private string ReadFile(string path)
{
    Monitor.Enter(this._locker);

    try
    {
        // read the file here...
    }
    finally
    {
        Monitor.Exit(this._locker);
    }
}
```

What the `Monitor` will do is ensure that the file will not be `read` until an on-going `write` operation is complete (and vice-versa). This will ensure that you will not get the old data when you read it, and you will also not over-write the new data (which has not yet been read). This method verifies the integrity of your files at all times.

Comment: How exactly does this work? If I understand it 'locks' the file until its possible to read/write? And in the reader, would I still just use a simple filestream reader?

Comment: @MarshalAlessi It will actually just put a lock on the object. So the method `ReadFile` cannot be executed while the `WriteFile` is being executed. You are actually *blocking* on the `_locker` object. So in other words only one thread can move past the `Monitor` at a given time until the thread who is busy reaches the `Monitor.Exit()` and is willing to give up the lock. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you for you explanation and answer! I do have one more question though, I just tested this method and oddly it now produces four lines of data per new file. IE, when it writes to the text file it duplicates the same line 4 times. What might be causing this?

Comment: Wow, I hope I didn't pressure you into accepting the answer lol. I won't feel bad if you choose a different one! Ok, for that I might need to see the code that is actually reading the file. Can you post that?

Comment: No pressure, it works so I accepted it. I originally had a simple streamreader line to ReadAllLines but have to change it for the issue. The issue is coming from the writer, each time I post a new file, and I look at the physical text file, I see that it writes four lines. For instance, I posted a text file name cavmsanass_Tracking.txt in the monitored folder, and usually it would write:

1080\Auto\cavmsanass_Tracking.txt 6/19/2016 5:42:16 PM

Now it writes:

1080\Auto\cavmsanass_Tracking.txt 6/19/2016 5:42:16 PM but duplicates it four times.

Comment: Hmm, I think we might be tackling two separate questions. I would post that as a separate question. Then, add the higher level code that *calls* the *writing* method `WriteFile`. Is that fair?

Comment: Yes sir. I'll tinker with it a bit and post it with the updated code later. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @MarshalAlessi happy to help.